# How to capture the File Version

Tags: php, arrays, api, cloud, podio

How to get the File version of the attached Files field. In case if its a pdf then how can we see the version through the API. Below I have attached 2files. 1st one is the attached file in the Podio view. and the 2nd one is API call so there I can't see the file version. Can you please assist me on this.
[Podio View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV8hD.jpg)
[Browser API View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mysG6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no versioning for a file attachment in Podio.

However, when you replace a file,
or
delete a file, and re-attach a newer updated version of the "same" file

then the file now has a brand new file_id

so instead of being referenced with it's old file_id
e.g.
https://files.podio.com/123456777

it will now have a new file_id
e.g.
https://files.podio.com/123456888

if you look at the way the API works you can do some experiments to prove this

https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/get-files-4497983

https://developers.podio.com/doc/files/replace-file-22450

Personally, I am extracting all file attachment file_id from the full json of the entire item_id when any webhook is received by our server for that item_id

Comment: Thanks for the update, I am able to upload files as well as get files from Podio. But my concern is when we are getting the files we can get(filename, filetype, filesize, attached by, etc.). What I want is like filename, filesize, can we get file version too?